# Rails3 with jruby war deployment on tomcat. I am able to access MyApp/public/index.html page. Fails to all other view pages

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tomcat6, war, jrubyonrails

I have debug my application thoroughly by using http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html process. I am able to see all logs which i have keep inside different init files, able to see print message which is there in routes.rb

Whenever i am trying to access any other path defined in routes.rb it fails and showing me same error all the time. I have checked log file also but not getting any useful information to further debug. Following is my log errors

> `Mar 18, 2013 7:53:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet files threw exception
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to invoke rails, please see the log for more details
>       at org.jruby.webapp.RailsServlet.service(RailsServlet.java:50)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:342)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
>       at org.jruby.webapp.FileServlet.service(FileServlet.java:207)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

Edit: I have noticed my rails-3.2.12 gems directory is empty. There is not files inside. Is there any thing to worry about for this ?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the application log file as well, please.  The catalina log above isn't enough to make suggestions just by itself.

Comment: @mcfinnigan These are the logs from localhost-date.log file. There is no logs in my App/log/*.log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its being long time, I am able to resolve my problem. It was due incompatibility of rails, jruby versioning problem. I was migrated my application from very older version of rails ie 2.2.3 version of rails.

Finally i did the hack created new application using new rails 3.2.12 and deployed it successfully on tomcat with the help of [Warbler](https://github.com/jruby/warbler). There is another ariticle to help for deployment on tomcat is [here](http://thenice.tumblr.com/post/133345213/deploying-a-rails-application-in-tomcat-with).

Another important point is in you tomcat directory don't give any white space in the path. for eg. C:\apache\apache tomcat-7.0.57\ this will make your application fail, instead you can give C:\apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.57. Make sure there is no spaces between the names.